# CS50 pset2 Caesar - Could someone please explain to me how this conversion of the key from string to integer isn't happening? Thanks

Tags: cs50, caesar-cipher

`#include <cs50.h>`
`#include <ctype.h>`
`#include <stdio.h>`
`#include <stdlib.h>`
`#include <string.h>`

// Alert C of our upcoming function to convert our plaintext into ciphertext to the scale of our key.
void ciphertext(string plaintext, int key);

`int main(int argc, string argv[])`
`{`
// Get argv[] ("key") from user.
`if (argc == 2)`
`{`
// Check whether key is a non-negative integer.
`for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)`
`{`
`if (isdigit(argv[1]) == false)`
`{`
`printf("Usage: ./caesar [key]\n");`
`return 1;`
`}`
`}`

```
    // Confirm receipt of key and convert our string into an integer.
    `int key = atoi(argv[1]);`
    `printf("Thank you. Key is %d\n", key);`

    // Get plaintext from user.
    `string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");`

    // Print ciphertext, converted from plaintext by our ciphertext function.
    `printf("Ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);`

    `cipher_text(plaintext, key);`
`}`

// For key entries that are anything other than non-negative numerical values, remind the user of the requisite format.
`else`
`{`
    `printf("Usage: ./caesar [key]\n");`
    `return 1;`
`}`
`printf("\n");`
```

`}`

`void ciphertext(string plaintext, int key)`
`{`
`for (i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)`
`{`
`if (plaintext[i] >= 'a' && plaintext[i] <= 'z')`
`{`
`printf("%c", ((plaintext[i] + key) % 26) + 'a');`
`}`

```
    `if (plaintext[i] >= 'A' && plaintext[i] <= 'Z')`
    `{`
        `printf("%c", ((plaintext[i] + key) % 26) + 'A');`
    `}`

    `else if (isalpha(plaintext[i]) == false)`
    `{`
        `printf("%c", plaintext[i]);`
    `}`
`}`
```

`}`

The following line:

if (isdigit(argv[1]) == false)
^

is giving me the following error message:

error cast to smaller integer type 'int' from 'string' (aka 'char *')

I don't know what it means. I want to cry. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Edit: the "^" should be under "i" in "isdigit".

Also, why is copy-pasting code into a text box such a nightmare here?

Comment: After code is pasted (or any text that needs to be formatted), select it in the textbox and click the `{}` in the format bar et voilà, it is formatted. You can choose the `Edit` button under the question and edit it the same way (select ,click) to correct the formatting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`argv[1]` is a string. [`isdigit` expects a char or int argument](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit). Program loops through `argv[1]` character by character, but never uses `i`.

Comment: Thank you, I feel silly now, but in a good way. I appreciate your simple explanation. The code now works!

Also, cheers for the tip on formatting code for sharing here. I tried highlighting the block to format altogether but it only allowed line by line.